# Plug webpack-dev-server and hot-load React with Tomcat

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm developing inside ecosystem that uses Tomcat server that servers all the files both java and javascript but the I run the javascript first through WebPack.

Is there any way that I can use webpack-dev-server and hot-loader for react/css/javascript files with running Tomcat server on localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#combining-with-an-existing-server